# Can't Load URL | Connect SNAP Auto Poster Wordpress with Facebook Fanpage

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have Wordpress blog and I want to share my post blog automatically in my Facebook Fanpage.
I using NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster plugin and insert App ID and App Secret (I'm already register in developers.facebook.com). But when I click Authorize Your Facebook Account, I get error that said:

"Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I'm already search answer in google, but still not able to fix it.
such as do this in developers.facebook.com account:

1. Use Strict Mode for Switch URIs => Turn off (but cannot turn it off)
2. Insert https://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback into Valid OAuth URI redirect (not solving my problem, having another error : URL Blocked)

Is there any way to fix it? I only want to share my blog post automatically to save time, just it. Any help is very appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: The error message is not talking about Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, but the App domains field – that is under Stessings -> Basic.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I put my blog url in "app domain" field and add platform website inserting same blog url inside "site url" field. is it wrong?

Comment: App Domain needs to be a domain only, not a full URL. Besides that, should be correct. Still the same error? Then check what value the redirect_uri parameter actually has, when the login dialog is called. Make sure that exact value (minus a `state` parameter, if set) is in your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field.